# Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: mysql

When executing the query, i am getting below issues.

> Error:Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> Error: Executing the query "
>
> ```
> DECLARE @@Temp_table TABLE
> (
> ROWNUM INT NOT NULL...
> ```
>
> " failed with the following error: "The statement has been terminated.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

```
-- DROP Table Block

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS YEAR_DATA_FUNC_RESULT
GO


DECLARE @@Temp_table TABLE
(
ROWNUM INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,MEMBER VARCHAR(15),YR_MONTH int
)
DECLARE @@OUT_PUT TABLE
(
    MEMBER VARCHAR(15),
    YR_MONTH int,
    LICS VARCHAR(5)
)

select distinct @

insert into @@Temp_table select distinct Member_Id,YEAR(SPlit_by_Month) as 'Year' from MEMBERS_BENEFIT

DECLARE @@ROWNUMBER INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @@Temp_table)

DECLARE @@COUNT INT=1
WHILE @@COUNT<=@@ROWNUMBER
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MEMBER VARCHAR(15)=(SELECT MEMBER FROM @@Temp_table WHERE ROWNUM=@@COUNT)
    DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(15)=(SELECT YR_MONTH FROM @@Temp_table WHERE ROWNUM=@@COUNT)
    INSERT INTO @@OUT_PUT SELECT * FROM LICS_UPDATE(@MEMBER,@YEAR)

    SET @@COUNT=@@COUNT+1
END

select * into YEAR_DATA_FUNC_RESULT from
(SELECT * FROM @@OUT_PUT ) a​
```

Comment: Hi there Ajay, try to describe what you are trying to accomplish and your expected outcome. Also, format your code and logs as code/fixed font so that it's easier to read.

Comment: This code looks like sqlserver , is the question tagged incorrectly or are you trying to convert to mysql?